# Setting a column of an align environment at a fixed distance from the margin

Tags: math-mode, align

I'd like to set proofs in the style shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79479/525) **but** with the right column at a constant distance from the left margin, so that the explanations show up consistently located in the many proofs I have in the document. FWIW, I'm using the `fleqn` option to `article.cls`.

Is there some extension to `align` somewhere which does this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method which works by using `flalign` and maintaining a fixed distance to the right margin of the rightmost, textual, part of the equation. Some adjustment to take into account the tag use the `calc` package facilities for dimension expressions.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{calc}

% The default width is here set to 5cm
% I quickly checked amsmath.sty to guess a reasonable way to adjust
% for the space taken up by the equation number: I imitated  how
% \tagform@ works by default was defined, and also saw there the 
% \mintagsep command.

% It seems to work here, but I have not tested the code any further and 
% I don't know how (not) robust this code will prove to be.

\newcommand\justif[2][5cm]{&&\text{\makebox[#1-\widthof{\normalfont(\theequation)}-\mintagsep][l]{#2}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
\quad\lvert p-q\rvert &=\sqrt{(p-q)^2} \justif{by definition of square root}\\
    &=\sqrt{p^2 -2pq +q^2}            \justif{by multiplication}\\
    &=\sqrt{p^2-2pq+q^2 +2pq -2pq}    \justif{by the additive identity}\\
    &=\sqrt{p^2+2pq+q^2 -4pq}         \justif{by grouping like terms}\\
    &=\sqrt{(p+q)^2 -4n}              \justif{by the distributive law}
\end{flalign}

\null\hfill\rule{5cm}{12pt}

\null\hfill\rule{5.5cm}{12pt}

\begin{flalign}
\quad\lvert p-q\rvert &=\sqrt{(p-q)^2} \justif[5.5cm]{by definition of square root}\\
    &=\sqrt{p^2 -2pq +q^2}            \justif[5.5cm]{by multiplication}\\
    &=\sqrt{p^2-2pq+q^2 +2pq -2pq}    \justif[5.5cm]{by the additive identity}\\
    &=\sqrt{p^2+2pq+q^2 -4pq}         \justif[5.5cm]{by grouping like terms}\\
    &=\sqrt{(p+q)^2 -4n}              \justif[5.5cm]{by the distributive law}
\end{flalign}


\end{document}
```

[image: rightaligned]

Comment: Great! Tags were what were messing up my attempts. I'll try and see how well this goes.