# Putting an equation with a long tag on a single line

Tags: equations

I m trying to put this equation with the author tag (Oppenheimer & Volkoff 1939) but the tag is too large to fit in one line. how do I put the equation and then the tag on the right side fitting in one line ?

```
\frac {dP}{dr}=- \frac {(P+\rho c^2 )\nu '} {2} \tag {Oppenheimer & volkoff 1939}
```

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
\begin {document}
\frac {dP}{dr}=\frac {-(P+\rho c^2 )\nu '} {2} \tag {Oppenheimer \& Volkoff 1939

\end{document}
```

and it's simply not working.

Comment: It fits in one line for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ7T8.png . Can you post a complete exaple starting from `\documentclass{}` and ending at `\end{document}`?

Comment: My answer to the closely related question might be of help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191993/how-to-properly-format-a-proof-explanation-with-multiple-points-of-alignment/192021#192021

Comment: First of all, type `\tag{Oppenheimer \& Volkoff 1939}`, as the simple `&` is an error when a literal ampersand is wanted.

Comment: @ Haqrish Kumar, can you please rewrite the code for me? unfortunately It's not fitting in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\begin {document} 
\[
\frac{dP}{dr}=\frac{-(P+\rho c^2 )\nu'} {2} \tag {Oppenheimer \& Volkoff 1939}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You forgot `\[ ... \]` and `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fourier}

\newcommand*\horse{\noindent Text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text.}
\newcommand*\differential{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand*\diff[3][\differential]{\frac{#1 #2}{#1 #3}}


\begin{document} 

\horse
\begin{equation}
  \diff{P}{r}
  = \frac{-\left(P + \rho c^{2}\right)\nu'}{2} \tag{Oppenheimer \& Volkoff, 1939}
\end{equation}
\horse

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that this answer is somewhat similar to [Papiro's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194912/15874) in as much as I also use the `\tag` command.