# Labelling aligned equations with text

Tags: align

I have an align environment in which the equations are numbered on the left. Can I add notes on the right (e.g. to explain where each equation comes from)?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can take a look at my answer to this question which seems to  be more or less related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191993/how-to-properly-format-a-proof-explanation-with-multiple-points-of-alignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    x&=y &&\text{comment for equation (1)}\\
    y&=x &&\text{comment for equation (2)}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]