# On making a real analysis book

Tags: margins, fontsize, theorems, book-design, proof-package

I am in the process of making a book for my own and not to be published of course about introductory real analysis, my main concern is about the format that I have to set in order to ensure maximum simplicity, aesthetic design, and clear for the user to read. I have looked at what some users have posted here such as this [Formatting and aligning real analysis proof](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365837/formatting-and-aligning-real-analysis-proof) and I found it to be not answering my desired question. I am looking for the following specification :

1. Font Size, margin size, and alignment.
2. Problem sets, theorem writing, and proof writing.

For (1) , the main concern is how related are font size with respect to the margin sizes and alignment. That is to ask, how should the font size and margin size be set to obtain an optimal resolution and a clear and easy to read text without confusing or finding it hard to follow when the reader looks at the text?

For (2) *I apologize deeply if this question might sound an opinion based, but I believe that opinions for this question is extremely limited*. My question is regarding the format of writing a theorem and writing a corresponding proof and likewise for problem sets and solutions to problem sets. What's best package to use in this case? I have seen some documents that have theorems and proofs framed inside a box. I would like to know if such environment adds a more clear texture for the reader and I would hope someone can recommend an alternative design for writing a theorem and a proof of a theorem especially if its a long theorem.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  While some aspects of the question are opinion based, there are often good reasons for differing opinions.  First, very long lines are difficult to read, or at least to avoid losing one's place; a length of 65-70 characters is usually recommended.  Text font size of 10-12 point is usual; 14pt is used for "large print" editions.  Theorem style often depends on the education level of the reader; a textbook for secondary school will be "fancier" than that intended for a doctoral candidate.  There are good packages for both.

Comment: Hello, thank you for writing me this comment, I apologize for my question I do believe it could have been improved and I will make sure next time to do so! I would like to thank you for your suggestion I will take that into consideration! @barbarabeeton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For theorem boxes, check out [the theorems library of `tcolorbox`](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#section.17)  There are other options as well, such as a `ntheorem` or `amsthm` environment wrapped in a `framed` environment.

I’m not sure if I understand what you mean by your other questions, but choose a font size that’s legible, and a layout that won’t confuse your readers.  If you’re asking, “Should I have ragged or justified text,” you want justified (and try the `microtype` package to improve the line-spacing!).  Displayed equations should normally be aligned at logical places.  If you’re asking, “Should I put equation numbers in the left or right margin?” either is good.

Like you said, you’re asking a lot of different questions and the answer will be opinion-based. The best page layout will also likely depend on whether you intend for your book to be read on the screen, or printed out on paper that costs money.  For instance, [Chapter 2 of the `memoir` manual,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf#chapter.2) and especially section 2.4, has one package author’s very detailed opinion of the correct answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! what I meant is that a lot of books have their texts written or focused on center of page while there are a lot of white space (margins) and some books have text covered entire on the page and thus which one would result in an optimal clear reading for the reader? and how would font size play a role?

Comment: @user231689 Like you said, you’re asking a lot of different questions and the answer will be opinion-based. It will also likely depend on whether you intend for your book to be read on the screen, or printed out on paper that costs money. [Chapter 2 of the `memoir` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf#chapter.2), and especially section 2.4, has one package author’s very detailed opinion of the correct answers.

Comment: Thank you very much once more! all is understood!