# Seeking a Good Latex Package for Formal Proof in Mathematics

Tags: proof-package

In most textbooks and theoretical papers, proofs are presented in natural language. Although it is impossible to present proofs in pure object language in our daily writing, presenting proofs line by line with clear indication of rule of inference and of source of reasoning in first order logic would be helpful for one's own thinking and for reading and understanding. I found one package named "logicproof", but it is not very flexible when line or even page breaks are needed for long propositions or large proofs. I am wondering if there exists a convenient and powerful latex package for presenting proofs formally.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27283/how-to-correctly-format-and-align-a-latex-proof

Comment: Without an example or code, it's very hard to tell, what you want. But maybe you can find something here: https://ctan.org/topic/proof

Comment: @DG' I am going to test several packages and improve my questions with sample codes and examples.